# How to load 404 meta tags when embedding a non-existent page?

Tags: discord, embed, share-open-graph

I am trying to make embeds for a website that I am working on that will show up in Discord, but that does not seem to work very well with 404 pages.

I managed to do that with my 404 page, when I embed the 404 directly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2vqK.png
But linking a non-existent page does not show the embed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwCrd.png
Does anybody know why? Any possible fix for that?